# Seemingly infinite loop

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

This loop is supposed to be looping through lines and when it reaches the end it should exit the loop. It seems to get stuck and not exit. I used an almost identical loop in a different macro so why doesn't this one work here?

```
    If not rs2.eof Then
        rs2.movefirst
        Do until rs2.eof

            Set ORDERLINE = ORDERLINES(CInt(rs2("ROW"))-1).VALUE

            If ORDERLINE("udfStringCol8") = trim(group) Then
                For i = 0 to (Lcnt - 1) 
                    Set ORDERLINE = ORDERLINES(i).VALUE
                    objExcel.Cells(i+2, 1).Value = ORDERLINE("PART_ID")
                    objExcel.Cells(i+2, 2).Value = ORDERLINE("DESCRIPTION")
                    objExcel.Cells(i+2, 3).Value = ORDERLINE("USER_3")
                    objExcel.Cells(i+2, 4).Value = ORDERLINE("USER_6") 
                    objExcel.Cells(i+2, 5).Value = ORDERLINE("USER_8")
                    objExcel.Cells(i+2, 6).Value = ORDERLINE("USER_7")
                    rs2.movenext
                Next    
            End If
        loop 
    End If
    rs2.close
```

Comment: My guess is that rs2 never hits an EOF. Your `movenext()` may not be executing enough times. Seems like the `movenext()` shouldn't live inside an `if..end if` and `for..next`.

Comment: Yeah.. Don't advance your recordset with `rs2.movenext` inside of your `for` loop. `rs2.movenext` should be just before your `loop` line. That advances the cursor of your recordset to the next record. You want to do that once inside your `while` loop. Furthermore, as @LynnCrumbling suggests, your recordset is never hitting `EOF` which suggests that your `IF` statement is always returning `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Do until rs2.eof
        If ORDERLINE("udfStringCol8") = trim(group) Then ' this doesn't happen
        'some code here
          rs2.movenext ' So this doesn't move next
        End If
    loop
```